# switching language requires users to login again

Tags: 6, i18n-l10n

I have a multilingual site, that when people switch from one language to another, they are required to log in again.

but if they switch to the language they switched from the user is still logged.

so basically you could log into my site with 2 different accounts.

how is this possible? any ideas whats causing this?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the issue [here](http://drupal.org/node/1337952) for [i18n](http://drupal.org/project/i18n).

It seems that the [Single Sign-On](http://drupal.org/project/sso) module should help you out.

> This module enables 'single sign on' between multiple web sites that
>   share common user tables (see http://drupal.org/node/2622#advanced).
>
> Single Sign-On (SSO) means that if you are logged onto the master
>   site, you will automatically be logged into any slave site that you
>   visit.
>
> SSO needs at least two Drupal sites running in order to use it (even
>   if you are using Domain Access module!). One is called Controller,
>   second (third and others) are called Clients. See README for more
>   information about setting this up.

I'd think that as the issue in the queue states the cookies are stored per language.  This should be amendable in `settings.php`.

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried to fix this?  This certainly isn't the normal behavior.  First, I'd do the following:

1. Try switching languages in a different way (change the language in the user profile vs. using a language switcher block, etc.)  Does the problem still occur?
2. Disable the i18n modules one by one (so long as there are no dependency problems) and test each time.  See if one of the modules is causing this.
3. If you only have two languages, add a third language to the site and see if changing to that language causes the same behavior.

It may go without saying but all of the above tests should be done on a local/test server, not your live site.

Comment: I think this is normal behaviour if multiple domains are used.

Comment: indeed we are using different domains, en.xyz.com and ar.xyz.com, but I don't want that behavior what can I do ?

Comment: If you read my answer then you should get your anwser :)